# Django how to display ratings as stars?

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm building a rating system for my website that is currently working with numbers. What I want is really simple :

1) In a template, displaying a mean rating as stars instead of as a number (I need to have partials stars, for example 4.3/5 would be rendered as 4 stars and a 1/3 star).

2) In a form, being able to click on stars to record a rating instead of entering a number.

For that purpose, I have installed django star-ratings. The problem is that there are no documentation available about how to actually use these app. I only want to be able to modify my templates to display numbers as stars and to record stars as numbers but I can't figure out how to do that. That seems so simple but I found nothing on the official documentation nor on internet.

Can someone familiar with this app help me ? Or is there a better way to proceed than using star-ratings ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: @ **Julien Mertz** , Have you tried this app?  https://pypi.org/project/django-star-ratings/

Comment: Yes that's the app I'm talking about, and like I said I found no documentation or examples about how to use it. I would be really thankfull if you could provide one little example about how to display a number as stars with it

Comment: this is front-end stuff. not related to Django. There are many javascript/jquery things you can use for this.

Comment: I know there exists things I can use, here I'm asking what thing is the most suitted for me and, if possible, having a small example because I found basically nothing on internet